# Instanciación mediante bucle a partir de datos externos (filas de csv)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, class

Es un tema sobre el que ha visto muy poca información en castellano y, aunque sé que esa información existe en otros idiomas, parece que no hay un consenso sobre cómo proceder en estos casos.

Crear una instancia de clase *manualmente* es un proceso trivial y está ampliamente documentado, pero ¿qué ocurre cuando queremos crear decenas o cientos de ellas a la vez?

Para documentar este ejemplo me he basado en un archivo CSV como origen de los datos, aunque se podría tomar una base MySQL o de otro tipo. En este caso estoy trabajando con la lista de youtubers más populares a fecha de hoy. Se pretende instanciar la clase Youtuber y crear 'n' objetos que contengan los datos de cada uno de ellos.

De esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pasamos a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente nos queda el CSV que es éste:

```
Username, Rank, Grade, Uploads, Subs, VideoViews
InfantiLandia, 1st, A+, 604, 6200598, 1670464213
Doggy Doggy Play Doh Cartoons, 2nd, A, 817, 9412116, 2907777208
Mikecrack, 3rd, A, 1119, 5474520, 1673283126
Funny Stop Motion videos, 4th, A, 1669, 5474293, 3245474807
Las Ratitas, 5th, A, 69, 5055219, 1105609473
VEGETTA777, 6th, A, 4646, 23370994, 9219285021
MikelTube, 7th, A, 546, 1759368, 1083350993
Mejores Juguetes, 8th, A, 1185, 8522816, 5520591071
Antena 3, 9th, A, 17797, 3679111, 4069343965
Willyrex, 10th, A, 4249, 11987094, 2745094454
DaniRep | +6 Vídeos Diarios De GTA…, 11th, A, 8075, 7652330, 3816892816
Pica - Pica Oficial, 12th, A, 144, 2524721, 2075300230
TheGrefg, 13th, A, 2122, 6900066, 1664491396
elrubiusOMG, 14th, A, 778, 30479075, 6802868265
WildBrain en Español, 15th, A, 975, 1135008, 389562451
Little Baby Bum en Español, 16th, A, 387, 6394223, 3862272020
Pocoyo, 17th, A-, 998, 5289731, 4281735020
Makiman131, 18th, A-, 2327, 8610363, 1969438160
Manucraft, 19th, A-, 3669, 3896799, 1294439199
TheWillyrex, 20th, A-, 5065, 14396647, 5006342830
DalasReview, 21st, A-, 756, 7902658, 1590795277
Bibon KidsTV, 22nd, A-, 485, 958899, 243581857
Cleo & Cuquín - Familia Telerín, 23rd, A-, 68, 2844719, 1207898041
Historias de Juguetes, 24th, A-, 595, 2195985, 942501452
TheChacal547, 25th, A-, 531, 1946846, 894423954
Adexe & Nau, 26th, A-, 123, 7361150, 2594144877
TiempodeSol, 27th, A-, 153, 1193472, 559811498
TOYS on the go!, 28th, A-, 768, 5002505, 3529201221
Pablo Alborán, 29th, A-, 140, 3281004, 2289520362
ElTrollino, 30th, A-, 1294, 3201308, 684603542
WhiteZunder, 31st, A-, 4129, 2879454, 863070151
AuronPlay, 32nd, A-, 337, 9573591, 1326842520
Got Talent España, 33rd, A-, 741, 1401777, 479678377
iTownGamePlay *Terror&Diversión*, 34th, A-, 4922, 10583351, 3332300098
Los juguetes de Arantxa, 35th, A-, 715, 1956684, 728476972
laSexta, 36th, A-, 12504, 929328, 1114063775
Sorpresas Divertidas, 37th, A-, 652, 1662332, 548316058
Nani Bebés, 38th, A-, 14, 112797, 22539966
LOLiTO FDEZ, 39th, A-, 762, 3715772, 347220338
Folagor03, 40th, A-, 5641, 3200102, 1386847376
Pinkfong! Canciones Infantiles, 41st, A-, 312, 980481, 382830321
Massi, 42nd, A-, 2270, 2952875, 860773000
Disney Junior España, 43rd, B+, 1424, 2366474, 1789631207
ElChurches, 44th, B+, 1567, 4602516, 1164374169
TikTak Draw, 45th, B+, 419, 3330126, 497092666
ToonToon Juegos, 46th, B+, 208, 1685632, 513653223
Telenovelas, 47th, B+, 9125, 279595, 342653783
BreakMan, 48th, B+, 182, 2289049, 340118860
xFaRgAnx YT, 49th, B+, 3687, 2570330, 623452670
Casi Bebes, 50th, B+, 101, 1270722, 415082181
```

Y ahora el código de Python:

```
import csv

class Youtuber:
    def __init__(self, Username, Rank, Grade, Uploads, Subs, VideoViews):
        self.Username = Username
        self.Rank = Rank
        self.Grade = Grade
        self.Uploads = Uploads
        self.Subs = Subs
        self.VideoViews = VideoViews

def importar_csv():
    with open (r'C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Tuberos.csv') as mi_archivo:
        dialecto = csv.Sniffer().sniff(mi_archivo.readline())
        mi_archivo.seek(0)
        tuberías = csv.DictReader(mi_archivo, dialect=dialecto)
        for i in range(0, len(list(tuberías))):
            índice[i] = Youtuber(list(tuberías)[i]['Username'],list(tuberías)[i]['Rank'], list(tuberías)[i]['Grade'], list(tuberías)[i]['Uploads'], list(tuberías)[i]['Video Views'])

índice = {}
importar_csv()
print(índice.values)
```

...pero me estrello una y otra vez contra `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Fíjense que si hago:

```
with open (r'C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Tuberos.csv') as mi_archivo:
    dialecto = csv.Sniffer().sniff(mi_archivo.readline())
    mi_archivo.seek(0)
    tuberías = csv.DictReader(mi_archivo, dialect=dialecto)
    print(list(tuberías)[0]['Username'])
```

Me devuelve el valor correctamente:

```
InfantiLandia
```

Pero en cuanto pido 2 valores o más:

```
with open (r'C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Tuberos.csv') as mi_archivo:
    dialecto = csv.Sniffer().sniff(mi_archivo.readline())
    mi_archivo.seek(0)
    tuberías = csv.DictReader(mi_archivo, dialect=dialecto)
    print(list(tuberías)[0]['Username'])
    print(list(tuberías)[0]['VideoViews'])
```

Volvemos a

`IndexError: list index out of range`.

Leeré sus ideas muy atentamente. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv.DictReader` **retorna un iterador** que va a ir retornando las filas del csv una a una en forma de diccionario dónde la clave es el nombre de la columna y el valor el contenido de la misma para esa fila. Básicamente un iterador es "perezoso", solo lee una nueva fila del fichero, la parsea y la retorna cuando se la pedimos, bien iterando sobre él o una a una llamando a `next(iterador)`.

Al ser un iterador, en el momento que haces `list(tuberías)[i]['Username']` iteras sobre el al completo y lo "consumes", por lo que la siguiente `list(tuberías)[i]['Rank']` es una **lista vacía**, lo que causa que al intentar indizar se genere un **IndexError**.

De todas formas, si haces `list(tuberías)` iteras sobre `tuberías` y creas una lista de diccionario con todas las filas en memoria, con el contenido del fichero completo, esto es realmente innecesario y muy ineficiente. Más aún cuando en vez de crearla una vez e iterar sobre ella, la intentas crear una vez por cada columna (6 listas por fila).

Simplemente itera con un `for in` sobre `tuberias`, como necesitas el índice como clave para el diccionario de instancias puedes usar `enumerate`:

```
import csv

class Youtuber:
    def __init__(self, Username, Rank, Grade, Uploads, Subs, VideoViews):
        self.Username = Username
        self.Rank = Rank
        self.Grade = Grade
        self.Uploads = Uploads
        self.Subs = Subs
        self.VideoViews = VideoViews

def importar_csv():
    with open (r'Tuberos.csv') as mi_archivo:
        dialecto = csv.Sniffer().sniff(mi_archivo.readline())
        mi_archivo.seek(0)
        tuberías = csv.DictReader(mi_archivo, dialect=dialecto)
        for  i, row in enumerate(tuberías):
            índice[i] = Youtuber(**row)
```

Dado que los nombres de los argumentos (*keywords*) del `__init__` coinciden con las claves del diccionario (columnas del csv) le puedes pasar el diccionario directamente usando `**`.

En vez de usar una variable global que es modificada por la función, es una mejor práctica crear el diccionario en la función y retornarlo:

```
def importar_csv():
    with open (r'Tuberos.csv') as mi_archivo:
        dialecto = csv.Sniffer().sniff(mi_archivo.readline())
        mi_archivo.seek(0)
        tuberías = csv.DictReader(mi_archivo, dialect=dialecto)
        for  i, row in enumerate(tuberías):
            return {i: Youtuber(**row) for i, row in enumerate(tuberías)}

índice = importar_csv()
```

Si las claves no coinciden con los argumentos del inicializador, simplemente llama pasando los argumento posicionalmente, obteniendo cada valor del diccionario mediante su clave (nombre de la columna en el csv):

```
Youtuber(row["Username"], row["Rank"], row["Grade"],
         row["Uploads"], row["Subs"], row["VideoViews"]
         )
```

o por palabra clave:

```
Youtuber(Username=row["Username"], Rank=row["Rank"], Grade=row["Grade"],
         Uploads=row["Uploads"], Subs=row["Subs"], VideoViews=row["VideoViews"]
         )
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se haría si las claves fueran diferentes?

Comment: ¡Sobresaliente, tenemos un ganador! :) Te confieso que hasta ahora no había visto `**` en ninguna pieza de código. Seguiré estudiando...

Comment: Rubén si el ingles no supone un problema en este enlace: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3 tienes un buen resume en lo que se refiere a `**` y el uso de `*args` y `**kwargs` en general.